# Linux Bash infinite loop with sleep

Tags: linux, bash, sleep

I am running a Bash script to execute a PHP file.

```
while true
do
    date1=$(date +%s%N | cut -b1-13)
    php /var/www/html/sprint/yii hello/validate
    wait
    date2=$(date +%s%N | cut -b1-13)
    diff=$(($date2-$date1))
    echo "$diff ms"
done
```

diff gives me back the execution time in milliseconds.

How can I ensure now that the script sleeps for

```
1200 - diff ms
```

to ensure that the PHP script is only called a maximum of 3000 times per hour?

Comment: what's the `wait` for there? i don't think it's useful at all.

Comment: the PHP script calls an external API on which i have a limitation of X calls / hour. It's just to ensure that the php script is finished executing before going on. If there's an API error the php script will loop until the API is back online.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need a sleep, like the one in GNU coreutils, that understands fractional seconds.  If yours does, then:

```
sleep $(echo "1.2 - $diff/1000" | bc -l)
```

Alternatively, your loop could be simplified to:

```
while true
do
        date1=$(date +%s%N)
        php /var/www/html/sprint/yii hello/validate
        wait
        date2=$(date +%s%N)
        sleep $(echo "1.2 - ($date2-$date1)/1000000000" | bc -l)
done
```

On the other hand, if we want to keep a printout of elapsed time:

```
while true
do
        date1=$(date +%s%N)
        php /var/www/html/sprint/yii hello/validate
        wait
        diff=$(echo "($(date +%s%N) - $date1)/1000000" | bc -l)
        echo "That took $diff milliseconds."
        time sleep $(echo "1.2 - ($diff)/1000" | bc -l)
done
```

Comment: Awesome. Simple solution. I have the GNU coreutils installed so this is working like a charm. Thanks a lot for the fast help.

Comment: Thanks for the simplification tip. But i want the output from the execution time on the console / nohup.out file.